# How to add interest on installments using BigDecimal?

Tags: java

I'm creating an application to sale cars and this application has the option to buy the car by installments monthly. Now, I want to add interest on installments. I'm using BigDecimal to do it and solve problems with rounding value but the problems is I cannot do it using BigDecimal. How could I do this using BigDecimal ?

Looking for how to do this, I found one recipe to calculate, the recipe is: 
**PMV = PV * i / 1 - (1 + i)^-n;**. But I cannot do it using BigDecimal.

> PMV = installment, PV = value of car, i = interest,  n = number of installments

I'm trying.

```
private void calculate(){
        /**
         * recipe
         * PMT = PV * i / 1 - (1 + i)^-n         
         */
        BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal pmt = new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal finalValue = new BigDecimal(0);

        BigDecimal pv = ValorBigDecimal.getValor(txtParcela.getText()); 
        Integer installments = Integer.parseInt(txtParcela.getText());
        BigDecimal inputValue = valorEntrada();
        BigDecimal interest = ValorBigDecimal.getValor(txtJuros.getText()).divide(new BigDecimal(100));
        BigDecimal rate = interest;

        //carValue - inputValue, check if financing has input value to subtract of car value
        total = total.add(pv).subtract(inputValue);

        //calculate        
        finalValue = finalValue.add(total);
        rate = rate.divide(new BigDecimal(1).subtract(new BigDecimal(1).add(interest)).pow(installments));
        finalValue = finalValue.multiply(rate);

        System.out.println(finalValue);

    }
```

Comment: At this point it would be helpful if you exactly mention the type of the problem and describe it in more detail. For example, is the problem that the code does not compile? Is the output incorrect? If so, what would you expect and what's the input? For me, it does not sound hard to compute a formula like `a * b / 1 - (1 + b)^-c` if `a, b` and `c` are given. Note that it says `(1 + b)^(-c)`. So `1/((1 + b)^c)`, do not forget the `minus`.

Comment: @Zabuza the problem is I cannot arrive to the final result. I cannot get the final result with installments and interest of financing.

Comment: Did you forget brackets in the formula in your question? It seems that you actually are trying to calculate this value: `PMV = PV * i / (1 - (1 + i)^-n)`.

Comment: @Zabuza I understand you. But the problem is I cannot do it using BigDecimal. If I use primitive variables for example `double` I can do but using BigDecimal I can't.

Comment: @AndrewLygin yeah, it is !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `rate` calculation. You apply `pow()` to `1-(1+i)`, not to the `(1+i)`. You also need to negate `installments`. So, there must be:

```
rate = rate.divide(BigDecimal.ONE.subtract(
           BigDecimal.ONE.add(interest).pow(installments.negate())
       ));
```

Comment: what is it `negate()` ?

Comment: It makes `-a` from `a`

Comment: Makes the number `x` to `-x`. Here's the documentation: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#negate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#negate())

Answer (score 0):

Quite hard for me to tell what's going on. You may start by separating your input from the actual computation part. Given your formula `PMT = PV * i / 1 - (1 + i)^-n` you can define a method like this:

```
public BigDecimal computeIt(double pv, double i, int n) {
    BigDecimal bigPv = new BigDecimal(pv);
    BigDecimal bigI = new BigDecimal(i);

    BigDecimal leftStuff = bigPv.multiply(bigI).divide(BigDecimal.ONE);
    BigDecimal rightStuff = bigI.add(BigDecimal.ONE).divide(BigDecimal.ONE).pow(n);

    BigDecimal result = leftStuff.subtract(rightStuff);
    return result;
}
```

You can then simply call the method, provide it the correct input and fetch the result:

```
// Input
double pv = ...;
double i = ...
int n = ...

// Compute the result
BigDecimal result = computeIt(pv, i, n);
```